# Get the actual class name in PHP

Tags: php, inheritance

The following PHP code:

```
class Base {
    protected function log($msg) {
        echo get_class() . ": $msg\n";
    }
    public function base_action() {
        $this->log("some message from base_action");
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    public function child_action() {
        $this->log("some message from child_action");
    }
}

$my = new Child();
$my->base_action();
$my->child_action();
```

will output:

```
Base: some message from base_action
Base: some message from child_action
```

As expected.

### My question:

Would it be possible for the `log` function (in class `Base`) to distinguish between the calling classes?

What I would like to see as output here, is:

```
Base: some message from base_action
Child: some message from child_action
```

### Tried:

I have tried using the `get_called_class` function instead of the `get_class` function and I have also tried using `get_class($this)`. Hoewever, both will return the name of the class that `$my` is an instance of: `Child`, even if called from the `base_action` function. The resulting output was:

```
Child: some message from base_action
Child: some message from child_action
```

which is not what I'm looking for...

I've also tried to 'override' the `log` function in the `Child` class and passing the value of `get_class` around in calling the `parent::log()` function:

```
class Base {
    protected function log($msg, $class = null) {
        if (is_null($class)) {
            $class = get_class();
        }
        echo "$class: $msg\n";
    }
    public function base_action() {
        self::log("some message from base_action");
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    protected function log($msg, $class = null) {
        if (is_null($class)) {
            $class = get_class();
        }
        parent::log($msg, $class);
    }
    public function child_action() {
        self::log("some message from child_action");
    }
}
```

This works, but kind of defeats the purpose of the inheritance. It is a work-around, but can it be achieved more directly?

Comment: It seems you are misusing the inheritance in a way you shouldn't. What is the purpose of logging `Base`, when you have a `Child` object? The very purpose of inheritance is to encapsulate at which class the method is defined, and to appear (to the "outside")as if everything was implemented directly in the child class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look up which class the last entry in the call stack had. The call stack itself can be fetched with [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace)

```
protected function log($msg) {
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    $lastCall = array_pop($backtrace);
    echo $lastCall['class'] . ": $msg\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of that! This acutally solves the issue regardless of how many layers of subclasses there are. Very usefull! (will accept!)

Comment: instead of ": $msg\n" you may use ": $msg".PHP_EOL to make sure newline will be rendered correctly on all platforms

Answer (score 0):

Check out debug_backtrace:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Parse through the callers/call-ees and save the traversal information as desired.